# 2006 Daihatsu Terios: What does this button do?

Tags: daihatsu

There an image of 4 wheels, the top 2 are tilted and there's a cross between the top set and the bottom set. I pressed it once and it made a noise that was less than pleasant and the car was revving weirdly. It took me 30 minutes to turn it off because pressing it again didn't work.
I'm driving a 2006 Daihatsu Terios

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was there supposed to be an image? Just put the URL in the body of the text and we can help you get it added if it doesn't want to play.

Comment: Updated with link to photo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That button is for the centre diff-lock.

The "normal" 4wd setting is the engine power is biased 60/40 to front / rear.

Once traction is lost, and any one wheel spins you are stuck.

Locking the centre diff "fixes" the drive to front and rear so if the rear has traction you will move, or if only the front has traction, again you will move.

However, if one front and one rear spin you are now stuck...

This should not be operated at speed on the hard-top and only in slippery conditions.

If it makes lots of noise then get it checked.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, i think it made noise because i was trying to drive normally (50+km/h). Now I know what it is I will probably never need it, but thank you again for answering my question.